# Is it possible to reference a property in package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json

Consider the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "expressapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {        
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mongodb": "^2.1.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.9.1"
  }
}
```

Now I want to rename my `app.js` to `index.js`. So I have to edit that name at least in two different places: main property and dev property of scripts. Is it possible to reference the value of `main` property inside package.json?

Comment: The package.json is just a file. Just load it as a file using the appropriate node library, use the JSON object to parse it, make changes, and then stringify it back into a file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it through [environment variables](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#environment-variables)

Under Linux

```
"scripts": {        
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon $npm_package_main"
  },
```

Under Windows

```
"scripts": {        
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon %npm_package_main%"
  },
```

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way that worked for any OS.

Answer (score 5):

JSON itself doesn't support variables.

It's up to the program consuming JSON that can decide whether to treat any particular pattern as a variable or to be replaced with some other text somehow.

While other answers have mentioned using the `$` or `%%` notation for variables (that are OS-dependent), I think you can also solve your problem in the following way:

Instead of `nodemon app.js` you can just write `nodemon .`:

```
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon ."
}
```

`.` will also automatically resolve to `app.js`

If you have a `"main": "app.js"` in `package.json` (in any folder, be it top level or sub folders) then any node process will identify the `app.js` file as the default one to load (either in `require` calls or executing via cli), just like it does `index.js` automatically.

Comment: this is totally not what they asked for

Comment: "If you have a package.json file for your app, you can omit the main script entirely and nodemon will read the package.json for the main property and use that value as the app" - [nodemon usage](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#usage). The `.` does seem to be necessary for `node` though. This method allows node to be used the way it's supposed to be, picking up the values in `package.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reference to any field value from `package.json` when executing scripts.
But there is a difference, when you run script under windows, you should use `%npm_package_field%` and with unix based OS you should use `$npm_package_field`.
Where `field` is field name from `package.json`.

Under windows, you can use:

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon %npm_package_main%"
```

Under unix:

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon $npm_package_main"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of NPM 7 you can do it natively using [npm-pkg](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-pkg).

e.g.

```
"start": "nodemon `npm pkg get main | tr -d '\"'`",
```

- `npm pkg get main` will give you `"app.js"`
- `tr -d '\"'` will remove the "quotes"